# ObjectBox query with Int

Tags: kotlin, nosql, objectbox

I'm trying to query with a `string` and an `int` field,

```kotlin
season = seasonBox?.query(
             SeasonEntity_.showIds equal it.show.ids.toString() and
             (SeasonEntity_.seasonNum equal it.episode.seasonNum)
         )?.build()?.findFirst()
```

I'm getting an error here:

```kotlin
(SeasonEntity_.seasonNum equal it.episode.seasonNum)
```

If instead of `it.episode.seasonNum` I add a static `Int` like 1,2,3,4... it works just fine.
Is it not allowed or I'm missing something?

Comment: What error? Is `it.episode.seasonNum` maybe nullable?

Comment: Error is something like `None of the following functions can be called with the args supplied`, `it.episode.seasonNum` is a nullable but I tried making it non-nullable still didn't work.

Comment: Ah, IIRC the method accepts long in Java. Kotlin does not auto-convert Int to Long. Check if adding .toLong() helps.

Comment: PS.: We're making this just work in the next preview. Thanks for your feedback!